# Chrome Border-Radius and Opacity poss bug?

Tags: google-chrome, opacity, css

Can anyone please help me with this, I have made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tRzc6/8/) to illustrate my problem...

When I try add

```
opacity: 0.6;
```

to the class

```
.menuitem {}
```

the border-radius no longer applies... Using the jsfiddle, try removing opacity and re-run it you will see what I mean. Is this a bug or am I missing something? The problem seems to be only in Chrome, but possibly in Safari aswell.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: The reason behind applying the border-radius to the .mask element is that the child divs .menuitem are marginTop animated in jQuery to slide down on mouseover. This means to have rounded corners on these items it needs to pass underneath the rounded mask as it were.

Hopefully that makes sense..

Answer (score 1):

set your background opacity using rgba:

`background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);`

http://jsfiddle.net/tRzc6/9/

Comment: Thanks for the quick respone, however, in the actual code I am using a background image, also I wish to apply the opacity to everything inside of the div. Any ideas?

Comment: hmmm... well if you do this http://jsfiddle.net/tRzc6/10/ it rounds `.menuitem` at the top only because of the hidden overflow, it may be related to that? Im not really sure.

Comment: I've updated my question to better explain why I am doing it this way and I cannot apply to border-radius to the menuitem itself,

Comment: Your question does make sense, and i have no idea what's causing that at all. I doubt it's a glitch though.